# how to use create a xml document with Xelement

Tags: c#, xml, xelement

I am trying to create a xml document using Xelement. I have a List of 2 objects, Data and Products. each has a list of objects. the xml document needs to be setup like this

```
<Property>
  <Points>
   <Sqft>1432</Sqft>
   <Price>45666</Price>
   <Product>Product Name</Product>
 </Points>
</Property>
```

Here is the code that I am using, of course it doesn't work but it is what I would theoretically need it to do.

```
var xEleProperty = new XElement("Property",
                        from item in Property.Data && item1 in Property.Products
                        select new XElement("points",
                                     new XElement("Sqft", item.sqft),
                                     new XElement("Price", item.price),
                                     new XElement("Product", item1.product)
                                   ));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below works, you need the Id properties to join the two collections, otherwise you will get duplicate records:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var data = new List<Data>();
        var products = new List<Product>();

        data.Add(new Data { ProductId = 1, Price = 321.0, Sqft = 789 });
        products.Add(new Product { Id = 1, Name = "SomeProduct 1" });

        data.Add(new Data { ProductId = 2, Price = 123.0, Sqft = 456 });
        products.Add(new Product { Id = 2, Name = "SomeProduct 2" });

        var xEleProperty = new XElement("Property",
                     from d in data
                     join product in products on d.ProductId equals product.Id
                     select new XElement("Points",
                                  new XElement("Sqft", d.Sqft),
                                  new XElement("Price", d.Price),
                                  new XElement("Product", product.Name)
                                ));
        Console.WriteLine(xEleProperty);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Data
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public int Sqft { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

the output is:

```
<Property>
  <Points>
    <Sqft>789</Sqft>
    <Price>321</Price>
    <Product>SomeProduct 1</Product>
  </Points>
  <Points>
    <Sqft>456</Sqft>
    <Price>123</Price>
    <Product>SomeProduct 2</Product>
  </Points>
</Property>
```

Answer (score 1):

if Serialisation is applicable i would use this (untested - sorry)

```
[XmlRoot("Property")]//you can change this if required
public class Property
{

    Public List<Point> points{get;set;};
}

public class Point
{
 public double Sqft{get;set;}
 public double price{get;set;}
 public string Product{get;set;}

}

public static void Main(string[] args) 
{ 
    Property p = new Property();
    p.Sqft = 4;
    p.Product= "Speaker";
    p.Price = 120;
    Serialize(p);
}   
static public void Serialize(Property p)
{ 
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(p)); 
    using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Xml.xml"))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, p); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean your file is not being created, use the `.Save` method for Xelement